# How to use Materialize css Tabs in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, materialize

New to Meteor.js and the [Materialize CSS Framework](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html). I don't fully understand how one would connect the Tabs to 3 different ones dynamically so when a user clicks it, the `.tab indicator`/`active` property slides over along with the desired route path. If I do this:

> client/app.html

```
  <template name="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs nav-tabs hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li class="tab col s4" id="nt1"><a href="/page1">Page One</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s4" id="nt2"><a href="/page2">Page Two</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s4" id="nt3"><a href="/page3">Page Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </template>
```

> client/app.js

```
  Template.layout.rendered = function() {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  }
```

The tab indicators work but it doesn't change the links to the rightful page. 
Its like its blocking the ability to go to page. I need help on how to do this, I've been at this for some time now. Thanks.

Comment: try `Template.tabs.rendered `.

Comment: @Mat. Damn it didn't work.

Comment: have you add some router??

Comment: @Mat. Like `Router.route('/page-one');`? If so, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another Update** if you dont want to define each tab you can do something like that

**Js**

```
//Manual Method
/*Template.tabs.rendered = function() {
   if(Router.current().route.path() === '/page2'){
      $("#nt2 a").addClass('active');
    }else if(Router.current().route.path() === '/page3'){
      $("#nt3 a").addClass('active');
    }  
    $('ul.tabs').tabs(); 
}


Template.tabs.events({
  'click #nt1': function(){
    Router.go('/');
  },
  'click #nt2': function(){
    Router.go('page2');
  },
  'click #nt3': function(){
    Router.go('page3');
  }

})*/ 

//Auto Method
Template.tabs.rendered = function() {   
    $("#"+Router.current().route.getName()).addClass('active');     
    $('ul.tabs').tabs(); 
  }


Template.tabs.events({
  'click .tabs li': function(e, t){
    var href = e.target.id;     
    Router.go(href);
  }  
})
```

**Router**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',  
});

Router.route('/', function () {  
  this.render('page-one');  
},{
  name: 'page-one'
});

Router.route('/page2', function () {
  this.render('page-two');
},{
  name: 'page-two'
});

Router.route('/page3', function () {
  this.render('page-three');
},{
  name: 'page-three'
});
```

**Html**

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> tabs}}

  {{> yield}} 
</template>
<template name="tabs">
    <!--Manual Method-->
    <!--<ul class="tabs nav-tabs hide-on-med-and-down">
       <li class="tab col s4" id="nt1"><a href="/">Page One</a></li>
       <li class="tab col s4" id="nt2"><a href="/page2">Page Two</a></li>
       <li class="tab col s4" id="nt3"><a href="/page3">Page Three</a></li>
    </ul>-->

    <!--Auto Method-->
    <ul class="tabs nav-tabs hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li class="tab col s4"><a id="page-one" href="/">Page One</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s4"><a id="page-two" href="/page2">Page Two</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s4"><a id="page-three" href="/page3">Page Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="page-one">
    <p>i am page-one</p>
</template>

<template name="page-two">
    <p>i am page-two</p>
</template>


<template name="page-three">
     <p>i am page-three</p>
</template>
```

Comment: This didn't really work. What it does is start the active state on the Page1 link but when you click Page2 it will go to Page2 without the active state and so on. You can get the active state on it by clicking it again. Need to figure how to get it to do the correct behavior. This is a good step though. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnHuntington ok i updated my answer this is a full working example.if you need to see it in action just tell me to uploaded it.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe useful if you are okay with rendering tabs without `Router`.

Let's say these are the templates you want to render stuff based on tab click:

```
<template name="page1">
.....
</template>

<template name="page2">
.....
</template>

<template name="page3">
.....
</template>
```

Now in your rendering area:

```
<template name="display">
    {{>tabs}}
    {{#if activeTab 'nt1'}}
        {{>page1}}
    {{/if}}

    {{#if activeTab 'nt2'}}
        {{>page2}}
    {{/if}}

    {{#if activeTab 'nt3'}}
        {{>page3}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Finally in your javascript file:

```
activeTab = new ReactiveVar('nt1'); //Your default tab

Template.display.helpers({
    activeTab: function(tab){
        return (activeTab.get() == tab);
});

Template.tabs.events({
  'click #nt1': function(){
    activeTab.set('nt1');
  },
  'click #nt2': function(){
    activeTab.set('nt2');
  },
  'click #nt3': function(){
    activeTab.set('nt3');
  }
});
```

Comment: That's good. I appreciate the answer. I will be practicing with the also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Template.tabs.onRendered(function(){' rather than 'Template.tabs.rendered = function(){'

In the end, your initialization of tabs should look like:

```
    Template.tabs.onRendered(function(){
      $("ul.tabs").tabs();
    });
```